# Determine for which constants a, b, c, and d it is true that f ◦ g = g ◦ f

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, function-and-relation-composition

f(x) = ax + b

g(x) = c$x^2$ + dx

So here's what I have:

$f ◦ g = a(cx^2 + dx) + b = acx^2  + adx + b$

$g ◦ f = c(ax + b)^2 + d(ax + b) = ca^2x^2 + 2acxb + b^2c + dax + db$

$g ◦ f = f ◦ g$

$ca^2x^2 + 2acxb + b^2c + dax + db = acx^2  + adx + b$

$ca^2x^2 + 2acxb + b^2c + db = acx^2 + b$

I'm stuck here and not sure what to do next. Did I go down the wrong path? Is there something I could simplify further?

Comment: In the first equation, where did the "b" come from?

Comment: What are the definitions of f and g?

Comment: Whoops. I changed it and added what f(x) and g(x) are equal to to make things more clear. Thanks for poiting that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algebra in your substitution was not correct.  $f\circ g$ is right, but $g\circ f(x)=a^2cx^2+(2abc+ad)x+b^2c+bd$.  When you set the two equal to each other and compare the coefficients of $x^2,x,1$, you get the equations $a^2c=ac$, $2abc=0$, $b^2c+bd=b$.

This gives you three cases, depending on whether $a=0$ or $b=0$ or $c=0$, and you should be able to find the proper restrictions on $a,b,c,d$ in these cases.

When $a=1,b=0$, $f$ is the identity function, so equality holds whatever $c,d$ are.  This shows that the condition $b+d=1$ doesn't always hold.  Also note there are combined cases like $a=b=0$, where $c,d$ can be anything, or $b=c=0$, where $a,d$ can be anything.

Comment: I simplified it to bc+d=1 after putting 0 in for x. Would b=(1-d)/c be an acceptable solution?

Comment: @Rionic Do you want all of the solutions or just some of them?  $b=(1-d)/c, a=0, c\ne 0$ is one family of solutions, but that family does not give you all solutions.  There are four more families of solutions, although they are all trivial in some sense (e.g., $f(x)=x$, $g(x)=cx^2+dx$ for any $c,d$ is one of them).

Comment: I think the main family of solutions should do. So I can say $b=(1−d)/c,a=0,c≠0$.

Answer (score 0):

First I would suggest that you move the $acx^2 + b$ to the LHS. As you want $f ◦ g = g ◦ f$, it must be true that $f(g(x)) - g(f(x)) = 0$ $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $f(g(-x)) - g(f(-x)) = 0$.

This should help you narrow down the "search space". And then you can substitute in any value for $x$ and get a equation. Using all these equations solve for $a, b, c $ and $d$.

I am also confident that it would be tedious to solve them.

Comment: So after doing all this I end up with b+d=1. Is this an acceptable answer?

Comment: @Rionic, First, I haven't solved it but, I suppose that should be one of the solutions. Other solutions are $a, b = 0$ $\forall c, d$ and $c, d = 0$ $\forall a, b$, I suppose you get these when you cancel out common factors from your equations.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.

Note:
This may be incorrect because
your problem may be stated incorrectly.
See my comments.

From
$ca^2x^2 + 2axb + b^2 + db = acx^2 + b
$,
we get
$(ca^2-ac)x^2+2abx+b(b+d-1)
= 0
$.

If this is true for all $x$,
then all the coefficients
must be zero,
so
$0
=ca(c-1)
=2ab
=b(b+d-1)
$.

If $b=0$,
then $a=0$ or $c=0$ or $c-1$.

If $b \ne 0$
then
$b+d-1 = 0$
and $a=0$
($c$ can be anything).

Comment: When you factored out ca from c$a^2$-ac, shouldn't it  = ca(a-1)?